# Voltage Divider-like circuit with multiple sources

Tags: voltage-divider

I'm extremely new to circuits and am having some trouble with a variation on the voltage divider problems I've been doing.

I'm trying to determine \$V_{out}\$ in the following circuit relative to some \$V_{GND}\$ that I need to determine the location  of

[image: F1]
.

I know that in a standard voltage divider, the line to \$V_{out}\$ carries negligible current. In this case, I can't quite determine the current flow because the lines from \$V_2\$ and \$V_1\$ carry current that is equal to \$V_2/R_2\$ and \$V_1/R_1\$ at the point in between the two resistors. How does this return to ground, and how would I begin to apply Kirchoff's Law for the loop?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMVdFp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I would think that ground node positions would be like this, but I'm nevertheless confused about the current flow. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is your vout connected to the ground?

Comment: Right, that wouldn't make sense. So V_out goes to some voltmeter that is connected to ground, but not to ground itself?

Comment: yes! It means you're taking the voltage at that node with respect to the ground.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can't quite determine the current flow because the lines from \$V_2\$ and \$V_1\$ carry current that is equal to \$V_2/R_2\$ and \$V_1/R_1\$ at the point in between the two resistors. How does this return to ground, and how would I begin to apply Kirchoff's Law for the loop?

Hmm. I don't agree with this. I think you came up with these equations with the old schematic, which had an extra ground connection.

The actual current through the resistors is
$$
I_1 = \frac{V_1 - V_{out}}{R_1}
$$
and
$$
I_2 = \frac{V_{out} - V_2}{R_2}
$$
Since there is no path for current to take another loop, these currents must be the same! That means that
$$
\frac{V_1 - V_{out}}{R_1} = \frac{V_{out} - V_2}{R_2}
$$
and some math gives you
$$
V_{out} 
= \frac{V_1 R_2 + V_2 R_1}{R_1 + R_2}
= \frac{V_1 R_2 + V_1 R_1 - V_1 R_1 + V_2 R_1}{R_1 + R_2}
= V_1 + (V_2 - V_1)\frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2}
$$
Notice that if \$V_1 = 0\$, you get back the equation that you're used to:
$$
V_{out}|_{V_1 = 0} = V_2\frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2}
$$

Comment: That makes perfect sense! I'll try to do the calculation  again myself, keeping this in mind. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome. Hit those upvote/accept buttons if it works out :)

Comment: Any chance you can clarify that "some math"? Im trying to replicate it but i get stuck, mine looks like $$V_{out}=V_2\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}+\frac{V_2}{1-\frac{R_2}{R_1}}$$

Answer (score 1):

It's still the same voltage divider. The only difference is that now your Vin is (V2-V1) and your Vout is with respect to V1. So Vout = (V2-V1)*R1/(R1+R2)+V1.